# What happens with extra memory using fscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to C and I have a couple questions about fscanf. I wrote a simple program that reads the contents of a file and spits it back out on the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[1])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: fscanf txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char* txt = argv[1];

    FILE* fp = fopen(txt, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", txt);
        return 2;
    }

    char s[50];

    while (fscanf(fp, "%49s", s) == 1)
        printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Let's say the contents of my text file is just "C is cool.", which will output:

```
C
is
cool.
```

So I have two questions here:

1) Does fscanf assume that the placeholder `"%s"` will be a single word (an array of chars only)? According to this program's output, spaces and line breaks seem to prompt the function to return. But what if I wanted to read a whole paragraph? Would I use `fread()` instead?

2) More importantly I'm wondering what happens with all of the unused space in the array. On the first iteration, I think `s[0] = "C"` and `s[1] = "\0"`, so are `s[2] - s[49]` just wasted?

EDIT: `while (fscanf(fp, "%**49**s", s) == 1)` - thanks to @M Oehm for pointing this out - enforcing strong limit here to prevent dangerous buffer overflows

Comment: Might be quicker to read http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that resource. I wasn't familiar with that website.

Comment: @austin If you're on a Linux machine, you don't even need the internet. Type `man 3 scanf` in a terminal.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks for the tip! I'm using cs50's IDE, so the scrolling isn't all that good with my laptop. Very jumpy and hard to navigate. When I get an Ubuntu server I will keep this in mind though!

Comment: Regardless what you are using, take Ed or Colonel's advise and spend the time required to read the man page. There are a number of subtleties with `scanf` that will cost you 50 times the amount of time it takes if you fail to do it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the advice. I agree 100 percent; the man pages are very helpful. As someone who is new to programming, though, I will say that sometimes they are difficult to parse. It's helpful to get a peer's explanation and then go back with a wider perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Does fscanf assume that the placeholder "%s" will be a single word
>   (an array of chars only)? According to this program's output, spaces
>   and line breaks seem to prompt the function to return. But what if I
>   wanted to read a whole paragraph? Would I use fread() instead?

The `%s` specifier reads single words that are delimited by white space. The `scanf` family of functions are very cerude; they do not normally distinguish between line breaks and spaces, for example.

A line is anything up to the next newline. There is no concept of paragraph, but you might consider anything between blank lines a paragraph. The function to read lines of text is `fgets`, so you could read lines until you find an empty one. (`fgets` retains the newline at the end, mind.)

`fread` is a function for reading binary data. It is not useful for reading structured texts. (But it can be used to read the contents of a whole text file at once.)

> 2) More importantly I'm wondering what happens with all of the unused
>   space in the array. On the first iteration, I think `c[0] = 'C'` and
>   `c[1] = '\0'`, so are `c[2]` - `c[49]` just wasted?

You are right, the data after the null ternimator isn't used. "Wasted" is too negative – with user input you don't know whether you encounter a longer word eventually. Because dynamic allocation requires some care in C, allocating "enogh for most cases"  is a goopd practice in C. You should enforce the hard limit when reading, though, to prevent buffer overruns:

```
fscanf(fp, "%49s", s)
```

The issue of "wasted" memory becomes more serious if you have an array of arrays of 50 chars. Most of the words will be much shorter than 50 chars. Here, the extra memory might eventually hurt you. 48 extra characters for reading a line are okay, though.

(A strategy to save "compact" arrays of chars is to have a running array of chars that is a concatenation of all strings, including their terminators. The word array is then an array of piointers into that master string.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for this thoughtful response. This question was in preparation for cs50's pset5, in which I have to load some 150,000 words into memory at once! So I think the wasted space could definitely cause an issue here - which is good to know. Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

You use specifier `%s` which will read and store data in array `s` until it encounters a space or newline . As soon as it encounters space  `fscanf` returns.

> I think c[0] = "C" and c[1] = "\0", so are c[2] - c[49] just wasted?

Yes , `s[0]='C'` and `s[1]='\0'` and you probably can't do anything about the size of array being much more.

If you want complete string `"C is cool"` stored in array use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

```
#define len 1000

char s[len]; 
while(fgets(s,len,fp)!=NULL) {
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! It's making more sense to me now. This definitely answers my first question!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'd add a vote but I don't have enough reputation :/ Thanks again for answering my questions!